# Scale symbol only in displaystyle

Tags: symbols, integral, relsize, scalerel

Is it possible to scale a symbol **with its default name** only in displaystyle?

For example, when calling `\int_{a}^{b}`, the results should
be

```
\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\int}}_{a}^{b}
```

scaled with two `\mathlarger` (from `relsize` package) in displaystyle math,
and `\int_{a}^{b}` in inline math?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
    
    Redefine \texttt{\textbackslash int} so that its scaled version is
    used only in displaystyle math.
    
    \[
    \mathlarger{\mathlarger{\int}}_{a}^{b}
    \]
    
    $\int_{a}^{b}$
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume you also use the `amsmath` package in your document? From your MWE as given there is no difference in size between the `\int` in displaymath and the `\mathlarger` version, but with `amsmath` there is a difference.

Comment: @Marjin Thank you. I overlooked but fixed it.

Comment: Avoid it. If you insist, look at the `bigints` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No support for `\limits` and `\nolimits`, sorry. It could be added, but I can't recommend using so big symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment if running LaTeX prior than the 2020-10-01 release

\RenewDocumentCommand{\int}{e{^_}}{%
  \mathchoice
    {\expanded{\noexpand\mathlarger{\noexpand\mathlarger\intop}\nolimits
      \IfValueT{#2}{_{\unexpanded{#2}}}\IfValueT{#1}{^{\unexpanded{#1}}}}}
    {\intop\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}\IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}}
    {\intop\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}\IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}}
    {\intop\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}\IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}}
}

\begin{document}
    
Redefine \texttt{\textbackslash int} so that its scaled version is
used only in displaystyle math.

\[
\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\intop}}\nolimits_a^b
\]
    
\[
\int_{a}^{b}
\]
    
$\int_{a}^{b}$
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: egreg Thanks. But I think you used the package `xparse`, and it was not written in the preamble.

Comment: @mert Oh, sorry! It's not needed if one uses LaTeX after the 2020-10-01 release.